# Given a function f, and a random range of input values with a range dx, what is the average maximum-value of f?

Tags: statistics, random-variables, expected-value

For example (but I'm most interested in a general procedure), consider $f(x) = \sin(x)$.  For a random, continuous range of values of x of width $\Delta x$, what is the average maximum value of $f(x)$.  In other words, for a uniform random variable $X$, what is the expectation value for: $$\max\left[f(x)\right] \,\,\,\mathrm{st} \,\,\, x \in [X, X+\Delta x]$$

I don't really know how to approach the *range of $x$* aspect of this.  For single value of $x$, I think the probability, $P(y < y') \propto \int_0^{y'} \sin^{-1}(y) \, dy $.  You could use this to calculate the distribution of expected $y$ values for independent, random $x$, but now for a continuous range (i.e. dependent, random) $x$.

Answer (score 1):

I was thinking about the problem in a bad way.  For a given $\Delta x$, the maximum value of $f(x)$ over that range is:

$$
\begin{cases}
\sin(x + \frac{\Delta x}{2})   & x < \frac{1}{2}(\pi - \Delta x) \\ 
1                              & \frac{1}{2}(\pi - \Delta x) < x < \frac{1}{2}(\pi + \Delta x) \\ 
\sin(x - \frac{\Delta x}{2})   & \frac{1}{2}(\pi - \Delta x) < x
\end{cases}
$$

Integrating this function, and dividing by $\pi$ then gives the average value for all $x$.

The answer (confirmed numerically), is $$\langle \max\left[\sin(x|\Delta x)\right]\rangle = \frac{1}{\pi}(2\cos(\Delta x/2) + \Delta x)$$